# Inductive definitions via a monotone operator

Tags: logic, induction, definition, monotone-functions

Aczel* defines the term **the set inductively defined by $\varphi$** as follows (p. 744).

> Let $\varphi:\mathrm{Pow}(A)\rightarrow\mathrm{Pow}(A)$ where $\mathrm{Pow}(A)$ denotes the set of all subsets of $A$. The operator $\varphi$ is *monotone* if $X\subseteq Y\subseteq A$ implies $\varphi(X)\subseteq\varphi(Y)$. [...] we write $I(\varphi)$ for $\bigcap\{X\subseteq A\mid \varphi(X)\subseteq X\}$ and call it the set *inductively defined by $\varphi$*.

Won't $I(\varphi)$ always be the empty set?

---

* Peter Aczel, *An Introduction to Inductive Definitions*, Editor(s): Jon Barwise, In Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics, Elsevier, Volume 90, 1977, Pages 739-782. ([link](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0049-237X(08)71120-0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $A=\Bbb Z$ and $\phi(X)=X\cup\{0\}$? I reckon $I(\phi)=\{0\}$.